# Extract keywords/tags from string using Preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following code

```
$str = "keyword keyword 'keyword 1 and keyword 2' another 'one more'".'"another keyword" yes,one,two';

preg_match_all('/"[^"]+"|[^"\' ,]+|\'[^\']+\'/', $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($matches); echo "</pre>";
```

Where I want it to extract keywords from a string, and keep those wrapped within single or double quotes together, this above code works OK, but it returns the values with the quotes in it. I know I can remove these via str_replace or similar, but I'm really looking for a way to solve this via the preg_match_all function.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword
            [1] => keyword
            [2] => 'keyword 1 and keyword 2'
            [3] => another
            [4] => 'one more'
            [5] => "another keyword"
            [6] => yes
            [7] => one
            [8] => two
        )

)
```

Also, I think my regex is a little be soppy, so any suggestions for a better would would be good :)

Any suggestions / help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about something like `a,"b",c,d,"e"` or `"b'" '"c'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it; you just need to use lookarounds to match the quotes:

```
'/(?<=\')[^\'\s][^\']*+(?=\')|(?<=")[^"\s][^"]*+(?=")|[^\'",\s]+/'
```

Comment: Superb!!!!! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much Alan M. 
Have just been trying to understand the regex you've used, and its beginning to make sense. To be honest, I've never come across the = before. Thanks again, really appreciate it

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html That whole site is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"|[^"\' ,]+|\'([^\']+)\'/',$str,$matches);
```

and use `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.

Comment: It would need to be:
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"|([^"\' ,]+)|\'([^\']+)\'/',$str,$matches);
and use $matches[1],$matches[2], and $matches[3] which again would require more manipulation after the preg_match_all function, so it would be easier to array_map a str_replace function that to merge the active instance of the array into one array.

Comment: How would you suggest that you join up the different arrays of results?

Comment: There's no native collating array merge function, so I'd write one, I suppose.  I don't fully understand what your output requirements are so it's hard to say what's most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this `tokenizeQuote` function](http://docs.php.net/strtok#53244) in the comments to the [`strtok` function](http://docs.php.net/strtok).

**Edit**   You need to modify the function because the original only works with double quotes:

```
function tokenizeQuoted($string)
{
    for ($tokens=array(), $nextToken=strtok($string, ' '); $nextToken!==false; $nextToken=strtok(' ')) {
        $firstChar = $nextToken{0};
        if ($firstChar === '"' || $firstChar === "'") {
            $nextToken = $nextToken{strlen($nextToken)-1} === $firstChar
                ? substr($nextToken, 1, -1)
                : substr($nextToken, 1) . ' ' . strtok($firstChar);
        }
        $tokens[] = $nextToken;
    }
    return $tokens;
}
```

---

**Edit**  Maybe you should just write your own parser:

```
$tokens = array();
$buffer = '';
$quote = null;
$len = strlen($str);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $char = $str{$i};
    if ($char === '"' || $char === "'") {
        if ($quote === null) {
            if ($buffer !== '') {
                $tokens[] = $buffer;
                $buffer = '';
            }
            $quote = $char;
            continue;
        }
        if ($quote == $char) {
            $tokens[] = $buffer;
            $buffer = '';
            $quote = null;
            continue;
        }
    } else if ($char === ',' || $char === ' ') {
        if ($quote === null) {
            if ($buffer !== '') {
                $tokens[] = $buffer;
                $buffer = '';
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    $buffer .= $char;
}
if ($buffer !== '') {
    $tokens[] = $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, as I would like it done with preg_match_all, but thank you. (Also the function doesn't work with single quotes)

Comment: But again, it doesn't take into account commas like my regex, only spaces. I am convinced that the best way would be to use preg_match_all, but if it can't be done, then I'll settle for a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

this requires a simple function to get what you want, but it works

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"|([^"\' ,]+)|\'([^\']+)\'/',$str,$matches);
function r($str) {
    return str_replace(array('\'','"'), array(''), $str);
}
$a = array_map('r', $matches[0]);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already looked into this but creates unnecessary workload. Thank you for your input though Galen